# Hibernate cascade save with OneToOne relation

Tags: jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables Users

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

and Carts

```
CREATE TABLE `carts` (
`id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
`user_id` BIGINT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ALTER TABLE `carts` ADD CONSTRAINT Cart_User_FK
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

I create entities for them

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Cart cart;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
public class Cart{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

I try to set cart instance to user and save user

```
Cart cart = new Cart();
cartRepository.save(cart);
user.setCart(cart);
userRepository.save(user);
```

but hibernate don't update cart table

repositories extended from SimpleJpaRepository

Could somebody explain me how to update related object?

Comment: You only initialize the inverse side of the association. You need to initialize the owning side: `cart.setUser(user)`

Comment: So, I have no possibility to save related objects by saving parent?

Comment: Sure you have. But if your child has a null property, then the column mapped to this property will be null too.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for your answer